# Message template token no longer available / relevant

Tags: wordpress, tokens, system-workflow-messages

After updating to Civi version 5.45.1 we have this notice:

You are using tokens that have been removed or deprecated.

Please review your contribution_online_receipt message template and remove references to the token `{$contributeMode}` as it has been replaced by `{no longer available / relevant}`

I have found the `$contributeMode` in the edited plaintext version of contribution_online_receipt:

```
{if $contributeMode eq 'direct' AND !$is_pay_later AND $amount GT 0}

===========================================================
{ts}Credit Card Information{/ts}.....
```

Is there a different token to replace this with, or is it safe to remove?

I was not able to find much documentation on this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes its safe to remove, so replace

```
{if $contributeMode eq 'direct' AND !$is_pay_later AND $amount GT 0}
```

with

```
{!$is_pay_later AND $amount GT 0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick